# Slow MERGE on millions of rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, merge, sqlperformance

I'm merging millions (1-10) of rows into a table that contains 20+ millions of rows.

Target table has 16 columns, 1 PK column (NormalID).

Problem I found is that some records have their PK column Ids changed. So for example record "A" with PK id of "12345678", will have its id changed to "4567890". Hence why I've put in a delete in the merge. I've limited the source pull of data to be 2 months at the time.

Source Table (this usually holds a month or two worth of data. For example year 2024 with September (9) and October (10):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[slowmergetbl_source](
    [sEntity] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [wYear] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [wPeriod] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [sAccount] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [wBracket] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [sCurrency] [varchar](3) NULL,
    [dValue] [float] NULL,
    [bDirty] [bit] NULL DEFAULT 1,
    [dFactValue] [float] NULL,
    [wEntityId] [int] NULL,
    [wAccountId] [int] NULL,
    [wTimeId] [int] NULL,
    [wExtDimId1] [int] NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    [NormalID] [int]  NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_SourceNormalID] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([NormalID] ASC)
);
```

Table script for the main table that is being merged into:

```
CREATE TABLE [reporting].[slowmergetbl_target](
    [sEntity] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [wYear] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [wPeriod] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [sAccount] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [wBracket] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [sCurrency] [varchar](3) NULL,
    [dValue] [float] NULL,
    [bDirty] [bit] NULL DEFAULT 1,
    [dFactValue] [float] NULL,
    [wEntityId] [int] NULL,
    [wAccountId] [int] NULL,
    [wTimeId] [int] NULL,
    [wExtDimId1] [int] NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    [NormalID] [int]  NOT NULL,
    [ModifiedDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [ModifyType] [varchar](10) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_NormalID] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([NormalID] ASC),
INDEX [IDX_Year] NONCLUSTERED ([wYear] ASC),
INDEX [IDX_Period] NONCLUSTERED ([wPeriod] ASC),

INDEX [IX_ReportQuery] NONCLUSTERED
(
[wYear],
[dFactValue]
)
INCLUDE ([sEntity],[wPeriod],[sAccount],[wBracket],[wAccountId]),


INDEX [IX_ReportQuery2] NONCLUSTERED
(
[sAccount],
[wBracket])
INCLUDE ([sEntity],[wYear],[wPeriod],[dValue],[wEntityId]),

INDEX [IDX_Normal_ModifyType] NONCLUSTERED ([ModifyType] ASC)

);
```

Merge statement:

```
merge reporting.slowmergetbl_target as a
using dbo.slowmergetbl_source as b on a.normalid = b.normalid

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE and a.wyear in (
2024
) and a.wPeriod in (9,10 )

THEN UPDATE SET
a.modifieddate=getdate(),
a.modifytype='DELETED'

when not matched by target
then insert (
[sEntity],
[wYear],
[wPeriod],
[sAccount],
[wBracket],
[sCurrency],
[dValue],
[bDirty],
[dFactValue],
[wEntityId],
[wAccountId],
[wTimeId],
[wExtDimId1],
[NormalID],
[ModifiedDate],
[ModifyType]
) 
values (
b.[sEntity],
b.[wYear],
b.[wPeriod],
b.[sAccount],
b.[wBracket],
b.[sCurrency],
b.[dValue],
b.[bDirty],
b.[dFactValue],
b.[wEntityId],
b.[wAccountId],
b.[wTimeId],
b.[wExtDimId1],
b.[NormalID],
getdate(),'INSERT')

when matched
and (
isnull(a.[sAccount],'')<>isnull(b.[sAccount],'')
or isnull(a.[sEntity],'')<>isnull(b.[sEntity],'')
or isnull(a.[wYear],0)<>isnull(b.[wYear],0)
or isnull(a.[wPeriod],0)<>isnull(b.[wPeriod],0)
or isnull(a.[wBracket],0)<>isnull(b.[wBracket],0)
or isnull(a.[wEntityId],0)<>isnull(b.[wEntityId],0)
or isnull(a.[wAccountId],0)<>isnull(b.[wAccountId],0)
or isnull(a.[sCurrency],'')<>isnull(b.[sCurrency],'')
or isnull(cast(a.[dValue] as float),0.00)<>isnull(cast(b.[dValue] as float),0.00)
or isnull(a.[bDirty],0)<>isnull(b.[bDirty],0)
or isnull(cast(a.[dFactValue] as float),0.00)<>isnull(cast(b.[dFactValue] as float),0.00)
or isnull(a.[wTimeId],0)<>isnull(b.[wTimeId],0)
or isnull(a.[wExtDimId1],0)<>isnull(b.[wExtDimId1],0)
)
then update set
a.[sAccount]=b.[sAccount],
a.[sEntity]=b.[sEntity],
a.[wYear]=b.[wYear],
a.[wPeriod]=b.[wPeriod],
a.[wBracket]=b.[wBracket],
a.[wEntityId]=b.[wEntityId],
a.[wAccountId]=b.[wAccountId],
a.[sCurrency]=b.[sCurrency],
a.[dValue]=b.[dValue],
a.[bDirty]=b.[bDirty],
a.[dFactValue]=b.[dFactValue],
a.[wTimeId]=b.[wTimeId],
a.[wExtDimId1]=b.[wExtDimId1],
a.modifieddate=getdate(),
a.modifytype='UPDATE';
```

Test data would look something like this:

```
insert into [dbo].[slowmergetbl_source] values ('1234',2024,9,'Test1',0,'USD',500,1,500,4567,1788,202409,0,505489215);
insert into [dbo].[slowmergetbl_source] values ('6795',2024,10,'Test2',0,'USD',100,1,100,0986,8897,202410,0,515456210);
```

Seems to be running very slowly, sometimes few hours.

Any recommendations on how to make this better and speed up the merge?

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the full table DDL. Please share the (preferably actual not estimated) query plan via https://pastetheplan.com. Your query isn't making a huge amount of sense: you are merging a table into itself, perhaps you should be prefiltering the source and target (using a view or CTE)? At the moment the only condition that is running is the `when matched` because every row matches itself on the PK.

Comment: @Charlieface i think it's two tables from different dbs, but hard to say :D

Comment: Yeah sorry, had a typo, that table was meant to be the reporting.slowmergetbl . The dbo one is the initial landing of data table, were i load data incrementally. So 2 months at a time for example. Same name for this example but diff schema.

Comment: the dbo table only has one index on the normalid col nothing else, as the job of that table is get some data then its truncated.

Comment: Please share the query plan as asked. You have quite a lot of indexes on the destination table, which will slow modification queries. You can remove `IDX_Year` as it is completely redundant against `IX_ReportQuery`. Consider whether any of the other indexes can be removed or filtered. Note that if you are comparing `NULL` with an empty string `''` or `0` then you may get unnecessary updated rows. Use `IS DISTINCT FROM` or `EXISTS (... EXCEPT ...)` instead of `ISNULL(...) = ISNULL(...)`

Comment: Have you tried getting rid of the numerous Casts and ISNULL's in the update section?  Why are you casting float columns to float?  Why ISNULL both sides?  If the intent is to update old values to new values then you shouldn't have to ISNULL both sides, shouldn't have to convert both sides, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of suggestions:

- check if you have index on `dbo.slowmergetbl.NormalID`,
- sometimes splitting MERGE into 3 separate operators (INSERT/UPDATE/UPDATE) can help, at least you will know which part causes the main delay, and can analyze its execution plan in details,
- you have too complex logic for checking whether update is needed ("when matched" section). Sometimes logic like this can lead to nested loops appearing in the execution plan, and very poor performance. Consider adding "hash" column into both tables, calculate it based on all fields that you compare (sAccount, sEntity, ...), it should look like `HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', CONCAT(sAccount,'|',sEntity,'|',...))` and use only this field to compare the data to decide if it needs to be updated.